# Why is NGINX giving me a blank page for my Angular app?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx

Here is my server block:

```
server {
  listen 123.456.78.90:80;
  root /home/pwa/dist;
  location /reportpwa/ { # if you have /, then it goes here on /pwa since its l>
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

The path to the dist folder is /home/pwa/dist as expected. When I point my browser to 123.456.78.90:80/reportpwa the browser just delivers a blank page.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Check your browser console or network tab? See what's failing?

Answer (score 1):

May be, you forgot set valid `<base href="/reportpwa/">`. Read: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Comment: You're the best yet. I changed the root to /home/pwa and the folder name to pwa. (cause I wanted it simpler) Then I added "pwa/pwa" to the base href tag and it works. I sure do appreciate it, sir.